# Rails Models with public/private access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm building an app with a `TodoList` model, than can either be private (one `User` to many `TodoList`s), or behave like a public group project (many `User`s to many `TodoList`s).

I currently have a column `is_shared` of type boolean, which determines whether the `TodoList` is private or public. However, my controllers are getting bloated as I try to handle user access permissions for both types.

Would it be better to have two separate models, `PrivateTodoList` and `PublicTodoList`, so I can handle each type with a separate controller?

Edit: here is a snippet of my TodoListsController:

```
class TodosListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user
  before_action :set_todolist, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authorized?, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :member?, only: :show
  before_action :admin?, only: :update

  # resourceful actions...

  private

  def set_todolist
    @todolist = TodoList.find(params[:id])
  end

  def authorized?
    if !@todolist.is_shared && @todolist.creator.id != current_user.id
      json_response('Not authorized to view or edit this Todo List', :unauthorized)
    end
  end

  def member?
    if @todolist.is_shared
      unless @todolist.members.find_by_id(current_user.id) ||
             @todolist.admins.find_by_id(current_user.id)
        json_response('You are not a member of this Todo List', :unauthorized)
      end
    end
  end

  def admin?
    if @todolist.is_shared
      unless @todolist.admins.find_by_id(current_user.id)
        json_response('You are not an admin of this Todo List', :unauthorized)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: One problem I see with two separate models is if you have functionality to make a private list, public and vice-versa. You would run into trouble maintaining the records in two separate tables.

Comment: Could you please post the way you are handling permissions in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single table inheritence (STI) on the model `TodoList` with a column `type` determining `PrivateTodoList` and `PublicTodoList`. The type of `TodoList` determines private or public property of your model.

create a migration to add column `type` to handle Single-Table-Inheritence of two different `TodoList` types

```
rails g migration add_type_to_todo_lists type:string
```

`TodoList` inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`

```
# app/models/todo_list.rb
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

inherited models (these are distinguished by column `type` on `todo_lists` table) inherits from `TodoList` class.

```
# app/models/public_todo_list.rb
class PublicTodoList < TodoList
end

# app/models/private_todo_list.rb
class PrivateTodoList < TodoList
end
```

So, with this setup, when you do:

- `PublicTodoList.new`, creates `TodoList.new(type:`PublicTodoList`)`
- `PrivateTodoList.new`, creates `TodoList.new(type:`PrivateTodoList`)`

You can use them as separate models for your app's model-to-model associations and business logic.

[more info on STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)

Comment: This is a great explanation of _how_ to use two separate models, but I'm looking for a _why_ or _why not_.